# I'm trying to use /b, but it doesn't actually backspace, but it inserts the character

Tags: python

So I've been trying to use the backspace (\b) character in my code, but for some reason, my python does not actually delete a character, it literally inserts a backspace character. Is there any way to go around this issue, or do I have to use another way?

My Code:

```py
print('Hello World!\b')
```

The output:

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: try `print('Hello World!\b ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this in IDLE , know that \b is not supported.